# Angular Material - md-tabs inside md-toolbar. md-tabs next to other elements inside md-toolbar

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

I want to have mf-tabs within md-toolbar and i use solution provided by Sithdown in https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1076

It works fine for me, but my problem is that i need to have md-tabs next to other elements inside md-toolbar, but for now, md-tabs is always underneath of other elements, just like that:

Image example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/I99fe.jpg

My code:

```
<md-toolbar>
     <span>saddsa</span>
     <md-tabs md-selected="selectedIndex" style="padding-top: 16px;">
        <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs track by $index" id="tab{$index + 1}" aria-controls="tab{$index + 1}-content">
            {{tab.title}}
        </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
</md-toolbar>

<md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-selected="selectedIndex" style="display: none">
    <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs track by $index" label="tab.title">
        {{tab.content}}
    </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

My code on Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/guKrRzB9F34mlFDqj4AS?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Check this out, the angular-material2 github has some demo-app example.  This will create tabs in the toolbar.
https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/components-examples/material/tabs/tab-nav-bar-basic/tab-nav-bar-basic-example.html

Basically, we need to use `md-tab-nav-bar` property in a `<div>`. I have a similar situation and was looking for answers. I have updated their code to include `md-toolbar`. Here is my example:

```
`<div class="demo-nav-bar">
  <md-toolbar color="accent">
      <nav md-tab-nav-bar aria-label="weather navigation links">
    <a md-tab-link>
      tab1
    </a>
    <a md-tab-link>
      tab2
    </a>
  </nav>
  </md-toolbar>
</div>
`
```

css:

```
`.demo-nav-bar {
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;

}
`
```

Comment: I have updated my answer...This was my first my answer. Thanks for information.

Comment: Looks better now, thanks. (Not my downvote btw, I lack domain knowledge to vote on this.)

Comment: Any reason for downvote.. ?I just happen to have a toolbar with tabs in it.

Comment: The link you posted is dead.

Comment: Updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
md-tabs.md-default-theme md-tabs-ink-bar {
    /* color: #ffff85; */
    /* background: #ffff85; */
}
```

remove these lines in css